# No module named 'PIL' (already installed Pillow)

Tags: python, module, python-imaging-library

PS C:\Users\hp\PycharmProjects\pythonproject> pip install Pillow
Requirement already satisfied: Pillow in c:\python\python310\lib\site-packages (9.0.1)

I tried this in the powershell i already installed it before
but now when i use this code in pycharm it shows this error

from PIL import Image,ImageTk

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'PIL'

Comment: do you have multiple versions of Python installed?  You may have installed Pillow in one version and PyCharm is using a different version.  Installations are version-specific.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.